# Is the cable-diagnostic tdr feature available on Cisco Nexus switches?

Tags: nx-os

I have a Cisco Nexus 93180 on NX-OS version 9.3.11.  I noticed that an available command is "show interface eth1/X cable-diagnostic-tdr".  However, when I issue the command I get an messages that says, "Time Domain Reflectometry(TDR) applies only to copper ports".

Firstly, the interface I'm issuing this command against is indeed a copper port. ...well, at least it's a copper SFP.

Upon researching the feature using trusty google, all I'm seeing is tutorials on how to use it with catalyst switches.  They state that I should run the "test cable-diagnotics" command.  My switch doesn't have a subcommand for "cable-diagnostics" when I enter test.

Any clarification would be great.

Comment: An SFP port is not a "copper" port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most copper SFPs don't support TDR, and even if they do it may not be supported in general in an SFP/+ port.

Found this:

> Cisco GLC-T/GLC-TX SFP module does NOT support TDR.

https://community.cisco.com/t5/networking-knowledge-base/how-to-use-time-domain-reflectometer-tdr/ta-p/3119327